# String concatenation using preprocessor

Tags: c++, c, string

is it possible to concatenate strings during preprocessing?

I found this example

```
#define H "Hello "
#define W "World!"
#define HW H W

printf(HW); // Prints "Hello World!"
```

However it does not work for me - prints out "Hello" when I use `gcc -std=c99`

**UPD** This example looks like working now. However, is it a normal feature of c preprocessor?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Concatenation of adjacent string litterals isn't a feature of the preprocessor, it is a feature of the core languages (both C and C++).  You could write:

```
printf("Hello "
       " world\n");
```

Answer (score 23):

You can indeed concatenate tokens in the preprocessor, but be careful because it's tricky.  The key is the ## operator.  If you were to throw this at the top of your code:

```
#define myexample(x,y,z) int example_##x##_##y##_##z## = x##y##z
```

then basically, what this does, is that during preprocessing, it will take any call to that macro, such as the following:

```
myexample(1,2,3);
```

and it will literally turn into

```
int example_1_2_3 = 123;
```

This allows you a ton of flexibility while coding if you use it correctly, but it doesn't exactly apply how you are trying to use it.  With a little massaging, you could get it to work though.

One possible solution for your example might be:

```
#define H "Hello "
#define W "World!"
#define concat_and_print(a, b) cout << a << b << endl
```

and then do something like

```
concat_and_print(H,W);
```

Comment: Is this a c++ standard or just a gcc feature?

Comment: In your example, concatenation is done at runtime not by the preprocessor.

Comment: Should you use `int example_##x##_##y##_##z = x##y##z ` ?

Answer (score 14):

From [gcc online docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html):

> The '##' preprocessing operator performs token pasting. When a macro is expanded, the two tokens on either side of each '##' operator are combined into a single token, which then replaces the '##' and the two original tokens in the macro expansion.
>
> Consider a C program that interprets named commands. There probably needs to be a table of commands, perhaps an array of structures declared as follows:
>
> ```
>  struct command
>  {
>    char *name;
>    void (*function) (void);
>  };
>
>  struct command commands[] =
>  {
>    { "quit", quit_command },
>    { "help", help_command },
>    ...
>  };
> ```
>
> It would be cleaner not to have to give each command name twice, once in the string constant and once in the function name. A macro which takes the name of a command as an argument can make this unnecessary. The string constant can be created with stringification, and the function name by concatenating the argument with `_command`. Here is how it is done:
>
> ```
>  #define COMMAND(NAME)  { #NAME, NAME ## _command }
>
>  struct command commands[] =
>  {
>    COMMAND (quit),
>    COMMAND (help),
>    ...
>  };
> ```

Answer (score 7):

I just thought I would add an answer that cites the source as to why this works.

The C99 standard §5.1.1.2 defines translation phases for C code. Subsection 6 states:

> > 6. Adjacent string literal tokens are concatenated.

Similarly, in the C++ standards (ISO 14882) §2.1 defines the Phases of translation. Here Subsection 6 states:

> > 6 Adjacent ordinary string literal tokens are concatenated. Adjacent wide string literal tokens are concatenated.

This is why you can concatenate strings simply by placing them adjacent to one another:

```
printf("string"" one\n");

>> ./a.out
>> string one
```

The preprocessing part of the question is simply the usage of the `#define` preprocessing directive which does the substitution from identifier (`H`) to string (`"Hello "`).

Comment: I notice that Mingw resolves string literals at the preprocessing stage. As concatenation operator doesn't work inside string literals.

Answer (score 0):

With clang on macos however it seems to not work anymore.
On macos clang the concatenation seems broken (example macro_broken.cpp):

```
#define CONCAT(p1,p2)  p1##p2

int CONCAT(hello,world) = 2;
```

```
 cpp --version                                                                     wschrep@walter
Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.1.0.2.5)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin23.1.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

cpp macro_broken.cpp
```

this outputs:

```
 1 "macro_broken.cpp"
# 1 "<built-in>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 3
# 384 "<built-in>" 3
# 1 "<command line>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 2
# 1 "macro_broken.cpp" 2


int hello##world = 2;
```

instead of what it should be:

```
int helloworld = 2;
```

So a##b does not concatenate here. Similarly the handy #a -> "a" also does not work.

A workaround is to use more params to our x macros in order to have different versions (but definately not ideal)

```
#define PLUGIN_METHODS \
  METHOD(plugin_execute_t, plugin_execute,  "plugin_execute", void,  void)  \
  METHOD(plugin_add_t,     plugin_add,      "plugin_add",     bool,  int, int) \
  METHOD(plugin_sub_t,     plugin_sub,      "plugin_sub",     int,   int, int)      


// generate typedef statements 
// example: 
//   typedef void (*plugin_execute_t)(void);
#define METHOD(name_t, name, name_str, ret, ...) typedef ret (*name_t)(__VA_ARGS__);
PLUGIN_METHODS
#undef METHOD

// generate function pointers
// example:
//   plugin_add_t plug_add = NULL;
#define METHOD(name_t, name, name_str, ret, ...) name_t name = NULL;
PLUGIN_METHODS
#undef METHOD
```

Comment: A workaround is to pass in more params to our x macro in order to avoid having to use the # and ## operations on macos. However our PLUGIN_METHODS define is more tedious to maintain.