# Weird C fprintf format notation

Tags: c, printf, format-specifiers

Trying to figure out a stack corruption error in a function when I noticed this piece of code:

```
fprintf( fp, "\n%s %3c %12s %2c %12s %2c %12s %2c %12s %2c"
             "%12s %2c %12s", 
             xys_field[3],      x,
             xyzFunc(val1, 0),  x, 
             xyzFunc(val2, 0),  x, 
             xyzFunc(val3, 0),  x,
             xyzFunc(val4, 0),  x, 
             xyzFunc(val5, 0),  x, 
             xyzFunc(val6,0) );
```

What I am asking is about this line `"\n%s %3c %12s %2c %12s %2c %12s %2c %12s %2c" "%12s %2c %12s"`, I don't even understand how this compiles since I never seen two formats follow each other like that. Thanks for any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [String concatenation using preprocessor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106280/string-concatenation-using-preprocessor)

Comment: Ok, I guess that from the plethora of answers you did understand that you can concatenate strings in that way ;) Can you tell us something about the type of xys_field, x and the return value of xyzFunc (even if I think it may print garbage but it won't corrupt the stack).

Comment: @Adriano The stack corruption error shows up at the end of the function. And there are dozens of statements like that. I doubt this is the one. Thanks anyways. I'll take care of the rest.

Comment: It's out of topic but I had a problem like that, usually the compiler "allocates" variable on the stack at the very beginning of the function (regardless where they're declared). I solved simply stepping line by line in debug with one eye on the ESP register (by the way finally it was a wrong calling convention :|)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are not two formats - notice the absence of comma, or anything separating them but whitespace. This is C syntax for continuation of a long string. In C, these are equivalent:

```
"abc" "def"
"abcdef"
```

Note that this only works for string literals; you can't concatenate string variables. This is a syntax error:

```
string1 string2
```

Comment: Haha, thanks. Can't believe I was never taught this / learned this on my own. Thanks. Accept in a min.

Answer (score 2):

In C, juxtaposed string literals (with only whitespace in between) denote a single string:

```
int main()
{
    puts("Hello, " "world!");
    return 0;
}
```

prints `Hello, world!`.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with format specifiers and everything to do with C allowing you to split a [string literal into multiple parts](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/glibc-manual-0.02/library_toc.html#SEC58) (e.g. across lines for clarity) and have it be concatenated.