# How does printf("Hello" "World"); work

Tags: c

I have started to write my first kernel-module and used the `KERN_INFO` macro.
The line itself looks like that

```
printk(KERN_INFO "Hello world");
```

So I was confused, why there is no comma after `KERN_INFO` and used the preprocessor to print the expanded version.

```
printk("\001" "6" "Hello world 2\n");
```

Now I was confused even more. I wrote a little program test this with `printf`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
        printf("Hello" "World");
        return 0;
}
```

Which works just fine, but why?
I do not think those are 2 arguments because arguments are comma-separated.
I know C ignores all whitspaces but I have never
heard of it concatenating 2 strings without a function.

Is there an official documentation showing that this is possible or how it works?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27485711/2564301) answer in the duplicate references the standards.

Comment: @Jongware thank you for linking to an answer which links to the official documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C concatenates string literals which are adjacent. So for C language:

```
"abc" "def"
```

is the same as:

```
"abcdef"
```

It's important to remember it only works on compile time literals, not on `char *` variables, so:

```
char s[10] = "abc";
printf(s "def");
```

wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Adjacent string literals are treated as a single literal, made up by concatenating the parts.

So `"Hello" " there " "world"` is equivalent to `"Hello there world"`.

Incidentally, the adjacent parts can be broken across lines (which is a bit hard with a single literal).

So

```
"Hello"
" there "
"world";
```

and

```
"Hello there world";
```

are equivalent.